# how to use media query pixel but different inch monitor

Tags: css, media-queries

I have 2 monitor and 2 pc having different inches 21.5(resolution  recommend 1600*900) and 22.5 (resolution  recommend 1920*1080) but both changed to 1366*768. I tried to use this my code but no idea how to detect inch and about DPI,DPPX,CSS pixel-ratio because both are the same, so I don't know what conditions to use , min DPI both are 96 and the other two are equal any idea to detect inch ? below is my css. Thank you

```
/* 21.5 inch 96DPI */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px)
and (min-resolution: 96dpi)
 {
  body{
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  #img{
    width: 50%;
  }
}

/* 22.5 inch 96DPI */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1366px)
and (min-resolution: 96dpi) {
  body{
    background-color: red;
  }
  #img{
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to get here, is not clear.

Comment: I want to use media query to detech inch from screen device or any idea to detect i have 2 pc but it will ez if user use resolution as pc recommend then i can set media min 1600 and 1920 but they set resolution to 1366 then that make picture to be inaccurate if u see my code u will see #img i think i will use dpi but both are same detail i check from mydevice io i don't know what i suppose to do for condition to check if same pixel

Comment: Because of not using the screen size recommend to the picture and then using 1366, the image in each screen size does not match

Comment: Is your page responsive or not? It's hard to see anything without seeing your actual page. If the page is responsive then there should be no issue.

Comment: page is responsive, but the image dimensions in the fields must be configured image is converted from the program 22.5 =255*255 ,21.5 =280*280 when user down to 1366 It moved a bit pixel because they want to use another program

Comment: The [media query documentation for supported features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#media_features) does not list a physical width of the device.